# How cameras receive Wi-Fi credentials from App?

Tags: wifi, iot

I bought a wifi camera and performed the simple startup process:

1. Powered on
2. Discovered the camera through the dedicated App
3. Set the WiFi credentials on the App to pass to the camera

After that, the camera gets connected to my WiFi network and I can use the device.

I'm curious about how the App passes the WiFi credentials to the camera. I tried a Wireshark capture in WiFi monitoring mode filtering with my smartphone `wlan.sa` but I saw nothing relevant. How does that work?

Comment: @nobody no it doesn't use BT

Comment: Usually the camera will set up its own AP for the initial discovery. Then, after configuring it will change to act as a client. They can use the same WiFi chipset for both roles.

Comment: @Ángel does that mean that the smartphone would disconnect from my WiFi and connect to the camera-AP? If so, I would have expected to find these data in Wireshark capture (wireless card in monitoring mode), but nothing

Comment: Not sure if disconnection from a wifi network would be something noticed at wireshark level. Does the camera app have a permission to configure WiFi?

Comment: @Ángel I'm not sure I understood your question. The app doesn' t have permissions except 'Storage'. Anyway, a wireshark capture of a wifi monitoring mode card should notice that